# Challenging differentiation problem

Tags: implicit-differentiation

I am trying to do it with substitution and getting a $1$ as answer but the answer is $\ln (4e^2)$

Given:
 $$ y = (1 + \frac{1}{x})^x + x^{1+\frac{1}{x}}$$

Evaluate $y'(1)$

Comment: What is the problem. We can't help if we don't know the problem.

Comment: Sir I am trying to upload a picture is not able to pls wait

Comment: Great! No worries. You can also type the problem in the question itself using MathJax.

Comment: Rather than a picture, you should use Latex. There are many Latex hints in this site.

Comment: I am giving you the drive link

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13oygM5JmpE-J0mSEt_f64k7a9cQQC10g/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: that's fine. I will edit your question to put the equation inside it. Please use MathJax from next time onward.

Answer (score 1):

First , we consider the following :-
$$g=(x+\frac{1}{x})^x \implies \ln g = {x}\ln{(x+\frac{1}{x})}\implies \frac{1}{g} \cdot \frac{dg}{dx}=\ln(x+\frac{1}{x})+x\cdot \frac{x}{x^2+1}\cdot(1-\frac{1}{x^2})\implies g’=(x+\frac{1}{x})^x\cdot\left(\ln(x+\frac{1}{x})+x\cdot \frac{x}{x^2+1}\cdot(1-\frac{1}{x^2})\right)$$ $$ \therefore g’(1) = 2 \cdot \ln 2 $$

$$h=x^{1+\frac{1}{x}}\implies \ln h = (1+\frac{1}{x})\cdot \ln x \implies \frac{1}{h}\cdot\frac{dh}{dx} =-\frac{1}{x^2}\cdot\ln x+(1+\frac{1}{x})\cdot\frac{1}{x} \implies h’= x^{1+\frac{1}{x}} \left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\cdot \ln x+(1+\frac{1}{x})\cdot\frac{1}{x} \right)$$ $$ \therefore h’(1)=2$$

From the above relations , we get $$y’(1)=h’(1)+g’(1)=2+2\cdot( \ln2)=\boxed{\ln(4 \cdot e^2)}$$

Comment: For $h'\left(1\right)$, note that $h\left(1\right) = 1^2 = 1$. The right side using the derivative gives $\ln x = 0$, so the $1$ term is $0$ and you just need to use $\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{x}$. However, with $x = 1$, it gives $2$, not $1$. As such, I get an answer of $2 + 2 \cdot \left(\ln 2\right) = \ln\left(4 \cdot e^2\right)$ instead.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yes you are right . Ty for spotting the error. Will fix it